# Excel Conditional Sum

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Sorry guys i'm a excel novice on dynamic formulas... but basically i'm trying to do a conditional sum using a different column condition for the condition and if the condition checks out use the value in another column

I want sum(b1:b4) but only when the value in column A meets a condition... So lets say i only want to sum the values in the range if the value in the A column = 3 ...

Hopefully that is clear.  Thank you in advance for the help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `SUMIF` for that.

```
=SUMIF(A1:A4, 3, B1:B4)
```

What it means, is, sum the range B1:B4 if range A1:A4 is equal to 3. Of course, it applies the condition on a row to row basis just like what you're looking for.