# How do I total an column of number conditionally in Excel

Tags: excel

In excel, I have a column of numbers such that if the number is positive, the text color is black, if the number is negative, the number is red.  How can I, in a fresh cell, total only the red numbers in the column?

Comment: http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/sumif.php

Comment: make sure you search before hand, this appears to be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22580579/excel-conditional-sum

Comment: You are assuming that I did not search prior to posting but you are wrong.

Comment: Having said that, this is a good reference although it doesn't show me how to define color.

Comment: your question did not ask how to define colors. If you want to define colors just use custom formatting. Also, in your case, you don't need to sum based on color, you can sum based on whether or not the number is positive/negative. The color is redundant,

Comment: Right you are, oversight on my part.  But, I don't think formatting is the issue, it's giving the color value for the comparison in the second element of the statement.  BTW, thank you.

Comment: are you trying to use =sumif(range, color, sumrange) ? Sumif doesn't work that way.

Comment: based on your comments, i posted a new answer, that shows conditional formatting of the text color, along with summation based on whether the number is positive or negative. If you need to sum based on colors, then you will need to write a vba function.

Comment: Right.  I basically was asking the wrong question.

Comment: You can edit your questions and answers at any point to improve/correct/clarify them.

Answer (score 3):

You can use: `=SUMIF(A1:A10,"<0")`

Answer (score 0):

Here is [my example](http://www.filedropper.com/book1_6).

In this example I have a range of random integers between -100 and 100. This range is `Sheet1!$B$3:$B$26`.

I have applied conditional formatting such that:

- positive numbers have black text,
- negative numbers have red text.

To do this, just highlight your range, set a conditional format using a custom formula, and set the format using the first cell in your range.

- custom formula for positive cells is `=B3>=0`.
- custom formula for positive cells is `=B3<0`.

I have created two cells which contain the sum of the table using the [sumif()](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/sumif.php) function:

- Sum of Positive Numbers: `=sumif(your_range, ">=0")`
- Sum of Negative Numbers: `=sumif(your_range, "<0")`

Note: that in your case, you said you want to sum the cells with red text, all of which are negative integers, so all I really need to do is sum the cells if they are a negative integer.
To truly sum cells based on a format such as text color, you could write a vba function/macro and iterate through the cells in the range.